# Function and distance on bounded set

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a bounded set $A⊂\mathbb{R}^n$ (for some n) and a function $f:A→A$ (not necessarily onto) such that $∀x,y∈A, x\neq y$ is $∥x−y∥<∥f(x)−f(y)∥$?

If such a set A (and a function f) exists, does there even exist such a set A and a function f such that f is continuous? (Or - can it be proved that such a continuous f doesn't exist?)

Comment: $R_n=\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Presumably you want to exclude the case $x=y$, because it is impossible to have $\|0\| < \|0\|$.

Comment: From [this page:](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5437292) "The American Mathematical Monthly Problem #4927 deals
with such a mapping. The problem is stated in AMM 67 #8
(October 1960), p. 809.  "4927. Proposed by David Gale, Brown University

Suppose $f$ is a continuous transformation of $n$-space into
itself, and suppose there is a positive number $M$ such that
$|f(x) - f(y)| \ge M|x-y|$ for all points $x$ and $y$, where
$|x-y|$ is the Euclidean distance. Prove that $f$ maps onto
all of $n$-space."

Comment: This is basically the same as your case (since our set is bounded, we can at least locally use compactness to achieve infimum, so that we can replace $> 0$ with $\ge M > 0$). As a second-hand source I can't tell you whether or not the original AMS journal actually proves that claim, but I'd believe it, and perhaps you can find the journal.

Comment: I cannot see how from this follow some of my theorems.